# Apple hardware-Apple Time Capsule

Tags: time-capsule

I work at a small international NGO.  We are looking into file sharing options.  The Apple Time Capsule has come up as a suggestion.  However, the catch is that we have people in NY, Argentina, and Thailand and we are all on different networks.  I would need something which we could all share/upload/retrieve files from/to.  We need a lot of space at low cost which is why we are looking into the TC and not file sharing options such as sugar sync, dropbox etc.  We are looking at 2TB of storage.
Are there any other low cost alternatives to the TC?  In terms of being able to share and backup files AND most importantly everyone from different networks have access to the same information.

Comment: I think a real NAS (network attached storage) would be the better solution.

Comment: If time is important to you you probably need something better that a single network drive used from all over the world